# HTML code inside JQuery html method not working (it shows the content but the javascript call is not working)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

To start I'm still learning javascript and AJAX so feel free to say everything that you want :)

I really don't get why this is happening: I have an Ajax function working very well, but if I post html content to call it again the AJAX function won't work in the content that it previously posted.

So here's the html code:

```
<div id="left-content">
<a class="clickme" value="1"> Option 1</a>
</div>
```

And this is my function

```
(function($) {
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: options.ajaxurl,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "action": "filter",
            "selection": $(this).attr('value')
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#left-content').html("Loading...");

        },
        success: function(data) {
                let html=``;
                html+=`<a class="clickme" value="1">
                Option 1 again
                </a>`:
                $("#left-content").html(html);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
})(jQuery);
```

So what I get after clicking Option 1 is

```
<div id="left-content">
<a class="clickme" value="1"> Option 1 again</a>
</div>
```

But if I click this it won't work now :( .

Comment: you should subscribe new elements to events each time when you insert them to DOM

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you be a bit more specific? I'm rather new in this so there's a lot of stuff I don't get yet :(

Comment: are you getting data back from ajax request? this piece of code `success: function(data) {`

Comment: Yes! I just erased the whole part where I use the data because the main problem comes from the specified "clickme" and "value" parts only.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem:
In the data property of your ajax object you set selection as

```
   selection": $(this).attr('value')
```

the anchor tag does not have a value attribute, it has val. Rename val to value and it should work

```
    <a class="clickme" value="1"> Option 1 again</a>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this val was just a typo here (my code had the value attribute well written). I'm going to edit the question, many thanks for your help :)